# c# encoding issues with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, encoding, iso-8859-1, csvhelper, byte-order-mark

```
var orders = new List<Order>();
....
orders.Add(...)


string csvstring;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var wr = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(wr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, false))
{
    

csvWriter.WriteRecords(orders);
    csvstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

And then

```
sftp.WriteAllText(fileNameAbsolutePath, csvstring, Encoding.UTF8);
```

The content of the file created in sftp has "feff" in the begining.
" orders.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8".

This is the first part of the problem. What I am looking is to convert this UTF8 to IS0-8859-1 as
the charset expected in the end file is IS0-8859-1.

May be I should do something like this ?

```
byte[] bytesSS = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvstring));

string s1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(bytesSS, 0, bytesSS.Length);
```

Tried to  google for "`<feff>`" and I quite didn't get the concept of BOM and a way to  fix this.

Comment: If you want to write as IS0-8859-1, why are you specifying UTF8 everywhere?

Comment: There's no `FEFF` involved nor would CsvHelper emit an HTTP Content-Type header. All applications can handle UTF8. There's no reason to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` either. What is that `sftp` variable and why are you writing to it with `WriteAllText`?

Comment: If you want to create a Latin1 file, use the correct encoding in the `StreamWriter`. Whatever `sftp` is I suspect it has a way of writing bytes to a stream. If you want to upload a file to an SFTP site you can copy the memory stream's contents to the target stream with `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)`

Comment: I kind of clubbed two questions together which created confusion. May be we can take up the first question now on UTF8 encoding before looking at the convert (pls ignore latin conversion for the time being). First I checked the current encoding of the stream (using new StreamReader(stream).CurrentEncoding) and found it be UTF8; and then tried writing the file to sftp using the same encoding;but it ended by with "feff"

Comment: If by `FEFF` you mean a *byte* with value `0xFEFF`, it's most likely a byte-order-mark. By default, StreamWriter doesn't emit a BOM, but `Encoding.UTF8` [specifies its use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-5.0#remarks). The reason is that although UTF8 files aren't supposed to use a BOM, *applications* have no idea of knowing whether a file is UTF8 or no until they encounter the first unexpected character.

Comment: @Hani it's not two questions in one - it's an unclear question. CsvHelper wouldn't emit a Content-Type header value. The BOM appears at the start of a file. What is `sftp`? There's no built-in SFTP class in .NET so you have to be using a different library. That library has a way of uploading a stream directly.

Comment: yes,sftp (SftClient) is from the Renci.SshNet library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea which SFTP class you use as .NET itself doesn't have an SFTP client. I'll assume you use [this one](https://help.crestron.com/simpl_sharp/html/M_Crestron_SimplSharp_Ssh_SftpClient_OpenWrite.htm) simply because it came first in a Google search for `sftp WriteAllText`.

If you want to create a file with a specific encoding, specify it in the `StreamWriter` constructor instead of `UTF8` :

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var wr = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(wr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, false))
{    
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(orders);
}
```

On the other hand, UTF8 and Latin1 (or any codepage) use the exact same values for characters in the range 0-127. If you want to send only English text, there won't be any difference no matter which encoding you use. If the actual requirement is to create a UTF8 file without a BOM, you can specify it by using the appropriate [UTF8Encoding constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_) :

```
var utf8NoBom=new UTF8Encoding(false);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var wr = new StreamWriter(stream, utf8NoBom)))
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(wr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, false))
{    
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(orders);
}
```

All SFTP clients have (or should have) a way to upload data using a stream. This means you can use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy data from the memory stream to the upload stream. Assuming [OpenWrite](https://help.crestron.com/simpl_sharp/html/M_Crestron_SimplSharp_Ssh_SftpClient_OpenWrite.htm) is available, you can modify the code to:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var wr = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(wr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, false))
    {    
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(orders);
    }

    ms.Position=0;

    using(var stream=sftp.OpenWrite(somePath))
    {
        ms.CopyTo(stream);
    }
}
```

When the CsvHelper completes, the MemoryStream's position is at the end of the stream and `CopyTo` wouldn't copy anything. By using `ms.Position` you move the position to the start of the stream.

Comment: Thanks! It worked now without the BOM.The app which picks the file from sftp expects it in ISO-8859-1. I tried switching to Latin and it worked as well. Can you explain how did the encoding in Latin work without doing any conversion from Unicode as the default encoding in .NET is Unicode (The orders object would be in Unicode as default)

Comment: Because ISO-8859-1 is the "official" name for Latin1. As for converting Unicode to Latin1, that's what the `Encoding` parameter in `StreamWriter` or `StreamReader` does - it specifies the encoding class to use to convert a string into bytes or vice versa. The default is UTF8 without BOM, which for non-accented English text is indistinguishable from Latin1.